# Using a try/Catch in a Do While loop

Tags: java, try-catch, do-while

I'm trying to use a try-catch statement inside of a do-while loop. The logic seems to work, but the do loop is not looping over and over. If it goes into the catch it seems to just break out of the do loop.

```
private boolean madeChoice = false;

public void whatToDo(){
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("=====================================");
    System.out.println("Welcome");
    System.out.println("=====================================\n");
    System.out.println("What would you like to do today? Your choices are: \n");
    choices();

    do{
        try{
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Please enter your choice");
            int numberEntered = keyboard.nextInt();

            if(numberEntered > 3 || numberEntered < 1){
                System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("That is not a choice. Please choose from the following: \n");
                choices();
                numberEntered = keyboard.nextInt();
               
            }else{
                System.out.println("That is a good CHOICE");
                madeChoice = true;
            }
          
        }catch (InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("This is not a number. Please choose from the following: \n");
            choices();
            
        }

    }while(!madeChoice);

}

private void choices(){
    System.out.println("1. Add a new set into your account");
    System.out.println("2. See all the sets in your account");
    System.out.println("3. Exit the Account Manger.");
}
```

Comment: It seems that you get error before setting the madeChoice to true, so madeChoice stays as false and the loop stops there. Maybe you should change the way you approach the problem. Is madeChoice variable really needed? When do you want for the loop to end exactly? Edit: you can set madeChoice to true in the catch clause maybe?

Comment: So I have the madeChoice set to false right above the whatToDo method. Sorry, I should have added that.

Comment: Don't you want to loop while `!madeChoice`?

Comment: I want the loop to end only if the user enters in 1,2 or 3. if anything else it should be caught by the if-else statement or if it's an error in the catch method.

Comment: When the user has entered an incorrect number, what value does `madeChoice` have? Will that value make the loop exit or continue?

Comment: If I set the while loop for !madeChoice it then goes crazy in the terminal with what appears to be everything looping over and over again forever

Comment: Then you chould set `madeChoice`to true only if the number is 1, 2 or 3 (so in the first if statement). And in the while check for `!madeChoice`

Comment: I updated the code to what I think is being suggested, and that is causing a never-ending loop when I add in the value of HH ( just a random thing to enter)

Comment: @CebrailYilmaz I think what you are suggesting is what I am trying to do.

Comment: You have a 'continue' statement into catch block, already try to remove it?

Comment: One last thing, cut the `madeChoice = true;` line and paste it into the if statement. After that your code should work as expected.

Comment: @tgdavies  The value of madeChoice should always be false unless the user enters a correct answer 1- 3 in this case

Comment: @DouglasOliveira I did remove the continue.

Comment: So the code that is there now is what I have. But when I enter say HH as an input... the terminal goes into a never-ending loop of things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `keyboard.nextLine()` before `continue`, when an exception occurs, you need to "eat" the input:

```
           catch (InputMismatchException e){
                System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("This is not a number. Please choose from the following: \n");
                choices();
                keyboard.nextLine();
                continue;
                // numberEntered = keyboard.nextInt();
            }
```

**EDIT**, I changed some of your code:

```
public void whatToDo(){
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("=====================================");
        System.out.println("Welcome");
        System.out.println("=====================================\n");
        System.out.println("What would you like to do today? Your choices are: \n");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        do{
            try{
                choices();
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Please enter your choice");
                int numberEntered = keyboard.nextInt();

                if (numberEntered >= 1 && numberEntered <= 3) {
                    System.out.println("That is a good CHOICE");
                    madeChoice = true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("That is not a choice. Please choose from the following: \n");
                }
            }catch (InputMismatchException e){
                System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("This is not a number. Please choose from the following: \n");
                keyboard.next();
                // numberEntered = keyboard.nextInt();
            }

        }while(!madeChoice);

    }
```

Comment: That worked! But it seems to still get stuck here
    if(numberEntered > 3 || numberEntered < 1){
     System.out.println("-----------------------=-");
    System.out.println("That is not a choice. Please choose from the following: \n");
    keyboard.nextLine();
    choices();
    }

Comment: I guess I can't add code into a reply?

Answer (score 0):

may be you can update your code to something like this, which seems to work for me:

```
private boolean madeChoice = false;
private static boolean isMissMatchException = false ;
private static boolean isInvalidInput = false ;

public void whatToDo(){
    if(Test.isMissMatchException) 
    {
         System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
         System.out.println("This is not a number. Please choose from the following: \n");
         Test.isMissMatchException = false ;
    } else if (Test.isInvalidInput) 
    {
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("That is not a choice. Please choose from the following: \n");
        Test.isInvalidInput = false ;
    } else {            
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("=====================================");
        System.out.println("Welcome");
        System.out.println("=====================================\n");
        System.out.println("What would you like to do today? Your choices are: \n");
    }
    choices();
    
    do{
        try{
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Please enter your choice");
            
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            int numberEntered = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();

            if(numberEntered > 3 || numberEntered < 1){
                Test.isInvalidInput = true ;
                this.whatToDo();
               
            }else{
                System.out.println("That is a good CHOICE");
                madeChoice = true;
            }
          
        }catch (InputMismatchException e){
            Test.isMissMatchException = true ;
            this.whatToDo();
        }

    }while(madeChoice);

}

private void choices(){
    System.out.println("1. Add a new set into your account");
    System.out.println("2. See all the sets in your account");
    System.out.println("3. Exit the Account Manger.");
}
```